# Does Google chrome automatically stop XSS?

Tags: php, google-chrome, xss

I have been doing some testing with XSS and I created a simple form with one text input and the php at the top of the page echoes out the value, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Mysite</title>
</head>
<body>  

<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];

echo $name;

}
?>

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" name="name"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I entered a javascript code in the text input like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('XSS!');</script>
```

When I do this in Google Chrome I get nothing, no output, no alert box and no errors. But when I view it in Internet Explorer I get the alert box as expected.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What does 'view source' have to say about the injected piece of code?

Comment: View source shows everything the same as before submitting the button. However when I enter something like this: <script type="text/javascript">alert('Breaking Bad sucks!');</script>lol123

....lol123 is echoed... So I guess browser is ignoring anything between and including script tags... which is wierd because I don't even have JavaScript turned off in the Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome has a built in xss filter:

http://blog.securitee.org/?p=37

and

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/does-google-chrome-protect-against-cross-site-scripting-xss

Answer (score 0):

because this is what you are printing.. no browser should protect that(or you shouldn't rely on that).. you have to convert all html by yourself :) `html encode` it...

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question, or may be I didn't get your answer.